Prove multiplicative inverse property involving a,b,c,d
Being the multiplicative inverse of a $\in \mathbb{R}$ denoted $a^{-1} = \frac{1}{a}$, $\frac{a}{b}$ is defined $a\cdot b^{-1}$
Given $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$, with $b,c,d \neq 0 $:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\ \frac{a}{b}\ }{\frac{c}{d}}&=\frac{a d}{b c} \\
 \frac{a d}{b c}  &=a d(b c)^{-1} \\
 &=a d\left(b^{-1} c^{-1}\right) \\ 
  &=a\left(d b^{-1}\right) c^{-1} \\ 
 &=a\left(b^{-1} d\right) c^{-1} \\ 
 &=\left(a b^{-1}\right)\left(d c^{-1}\right) \\ 
 &=\frac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{d}{c} 
\end{align*}$$
How can I continue the proof? I need to get the rational form again, but I'm not sure how to get there, considering the $-1$ is affecting $c$ and not $d$, besides I'd say there's an missing exponent affecting both as a whole, like
$(cd^{-1})^{-1}$

At the top you use $(bc)^{-1}= b^{-1}c^{-1}$.  Us it again at the bottom $\frac ab\cdot \frac dc = ab^{-1}dc^{-1} = (ad)(b^{-1}c^{-1}) = (ad)(bc)^{-1} = \frac {ad}{bc}$.

First as  lemmas prove that  $(m^{-1})^{-1}= m$ and  $(mn)^{-1} = m^{-1}n^{-1}$.  We do this by noting that
$m\cdot m^{-1} =1$ so by definition as multiplying $m^{-1}$ by $m$ yields $1$, $m$ is the multiplicative inverse of $m^{-1}$.  i.e. $m=(m^{-1})^{-1}$
and
$(m^{-1}n^{-1})\cdot (mn) = m^{-1}n^{-1}mn= m^{-1}mn^{-1}n=(m^{-1}m)(n^{-1}n)=1\cdot 1 = 1$.  So as $(m^{-1}n^{-1})\cdot (mn) =1$ by definition $m^{-1}n^{-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $mn$. i.e. $m^{-1}n^{-1}=(mn)^{-1}$
Then its just shuffling
$\frac {\frac ab}{\frac cd} = (ab^{-1})(cd^{-1})^{-1}=$
$(ab^{-1})(c^{-1}(d^{-1})^{-1})=(ab^{-1})(c^{-1}d)=$
$ab^{-1}c^{-1}d = adb^{-1}c^{-1}= (ad)(b^{-1}c^{-1})=$
$(ad)(bc)^{-1}= \frac {ad}{bc}$.
.....
Alternatively ....
Don't get hung up on converting to notation and back
$\frac {\frac ab}{\frac cd}$ is notation for $(ab^{-1})(cd^{-1})^{-1}$ and $\frac {ad}{bc}$ is notation for $(ad)(bc)^{-1}$.
So you need to prove $(ab^{-1})(cd^{-1})^{-1}= (ad)(bc)^{-1}$.  It's pretty clear from you first steps you know how do do that.
....
Alternatively 2
.....
Go as far as you can in each direction and meet in the middle:
$\frac {\frac ab}{\frac cd} = (ab^{-1})(cd^{-1})^{-1}= ab^{-1}c^{-1}(d^{-1})^{-1}= ab^{-1}c^{-1}d$ and that's about as far as we can go spreading things out.
$\frac {ad}{bc} = (ad)(bc)^{-1}=adb^{-1}c^{-1}$ and that as far as we can go spreading things out.
But $ab^{-1}c^{-1}d = adb^{-1}c^{-1}$, obviously (by commutivity), so we are done.

First, note that for any non-zero $x \in \mathbb R$, $(x^{-1})^{-1}=x$. This is because $(x^{-1})^{-1}x^{-1}=1=xx^{-1}$ and multiplicative inverses are unique. Now, starting with your equation, we have
$$\frac{\frac ab}{\frac cd}=(ab^{-1})(cd^{-1})^{-1}$$
$$=ab^{-1}c^{-1}(d^{-1})^{-1}$$
$$=ab^{-1}c^{-1}d$$
$$=adb^{-1}c^{-1}$$
$$=ad(bc)^{-1}$$
$$=\frac{ad}{bc}$$
